# Horizontal Pod Autoscaler (HPA) on Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) using Backend Latency from an Ingress LoadBalancer via Stackdriver External Metric

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to configure a Horizontal Pod Autoscaler (HPA) on Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) using External Metrics from an Ingress LoadBalancer, basing the configuration on instructions such as

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/external-metrics-autoscaling 
and
https://blog.doit-intl.com/autoscaling-k8s-hpa-with-google-http-s-load-balancer-rps-stackdriver-metric-92db0a28e1ea

With an HPA like

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: my-api
  namespace: production
spec:
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 20
  metrics:
  - external:
      metricName: loadbalancing.googleapis.com|https|request_count
      metricSelector:
        matchLabels:
          resource.labels.forwarding_rule_name: k8s-fws-production-lb-my-api--63e2a8ddaae70
      targetAverageValue: "1"
    type: External
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-api
```

the autoscaler does kick in when the request count rises - but placing heavy load on the service, like 100 simultaneous requests per second, doesn't increase the external metric `request_count` much beyond 6 RPS, while the observed `backend_latencies` metric in Stackdriver does increase significantly; so I'd like to utilise that metric by adding to the HPA configuration, like so:

```
  - external:
      metricName: loadbalancing.googleapis.com|https|backend_latencies
      metricSelector:
        matchLabels:
          resource.labels.forwarding_rule_name: k8s-fws-production-lb-my-api--63e2a8ddaae70
      targetValue: "3000"
    type: External
```

but that results in the error:

`...unable to fetch metrics from external metrics API: googleapi: Error 400: Field aggregation.perSeriesAligner had an invalid value of "ALIGN_RATE": The aligner cannot be applied to metrics with kind DELTA and value type DISTRIBUTION., badRequest`

which can be observed with the command

```
$ kubectl describe hpa -n production
```

or by visiting

http://localhost:8080/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/loadbalancing.googleapis.com%7Chttps%7Cbackend_latencies

after setting up a proxy with

```
$ kubectl proxy --port=8080
```

Are `https/backend_latencies` or [`https/total_latencies`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-loadbalancing) not supported as External Stackdriver Metrics in an HPA configuration for GKE?

Comment: Any luck here??  I am facing similar issues

Answer (score 2):

Maybe someone would find this helpful, though the question is old.

My working config looks like next:

```
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 95
  - type: External
    external:
      metric:
       name: loadbalancing.googleapis.com|https|backend_latencies
       selector:
         matchLabels:
           resource.labels.backend_name: frontend
           metric.labels.proxy_continent: Europe
           reducer: REDUCE_PERCENTILE_95
      target:
        type: Value
        value: "79.5"
```

`type: Value` used because it's the only way to not divide the metric value by the replica number.

`reducer: REDUCE_PERCENTILE_95` used to work only with a single value of the distribution ([source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/blob/master/custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter/pkg/adapter/translator/query_builder.go#L44)).

Also, I edited `custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter` deployment to look like this:

```
  - image: gcr.io/gke-release/custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter:v0.12.2-gke.0
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: pod-custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter
    command:
    - /adapter
    - --use-new-resource-model=true
    - --fallback-for-container-metrics=true
    - --enable-distribution-support=true
```

The thing is this key `enable-distribution-support=true`, which enables working with distribution kind of metrics.